# How to execute ajax requests in a loop, and before some code

Tags: javascript, ajax, alfresco

Is there a way to execute an alfresco ajax request successCallback before some code.
I can't put the code in the successCallback, here's how it looks like.

```
do{var serviceUrl = "/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/search?" + newSRequest;
        Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({
            url: serviceUrl,
            successCallback:{
                fn: function(response){

                    var items = response.json.items;

                    for (var i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++){
                        var nodeRef = items[i].nodeRef;

                        if (_this.nodeRefParameter.length > 0){
                            _this.nodeRefParameter += ",";
                        }
                        _this.nodeRefParameter += nodeRef;
                    }
                },
                scope: this
            },
            failureMessage: "Erreur Technique - Impossible d'executer le service: '" + serviceUrl + "'",
            execScripts: true
        });

        i++;
    } while( i * NB_RESULTS_PER_PAGE < (this.totalRecords < MAX_RESULTS_EXPORTED ? this.totalRecords : MAX_RESULTS_EXPORTED) );

    var inputHiddenNodeRefs = document.getElementById("nodeRefs");
    inputHiddenNodeRefs.setAttribute("value", _this.nodeRefParameter);

    var formulaire = document.getElementById("formExportSearchResults");
    formulaire.submit();
```

Comment: try use  beforeSend: function() { ...code... } just after url: serviceUrl,

Comment: @m-t Actually the code is a little bit more complicated. In each loop iteration there is an ajax request which updates the variable nodeRefParameter. The final value of this variable is submitted with the form. The problem is that it's submitted before being updated by the sequence of ajax requests. The successCallback function is being executed after all other code.

Comment: @m-t Besides, beforeSend handler allows to execute code before successCallback or after it? I need to execute the code after.

Comment: i don't exactly know what you are trying to do before and after, with your ajax call, your question was how to put some code before successCallback, and through beforeSend: function() {...} you can achieve it.

Comment: no this beforeSend for sure execute code before successCallback will execute,

Comment: @m-t Actually what I want is to execute it after the successCallback handler which updates a variable (nodeRefParameter) to be used in the code following the Ajax requests. Besides it looks like executing ajax requests in a loop does not work. I need a way to chain these requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of firing XHR calls in a do-while-loop is a very 'dirty' approach in general. So, depending on your use case there is better design approach, e.g. wire-up your own WebScript that is only called once.
Always keep in mind that XHR response is handled asynchronously, so you cannot be sure that your callbacksare executed in the same way as your XHR calls have been triggered.

If it comes to JavaScript  & chaining then promises/futures is the way to go. Unfortunately, Alfresco uses a pretty old YUI version were promise are not built in, but you can add a promises-lib on your own, e.g.: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Maybe, you should describe your use case / requirement in more detail, especially regarding the role of the nodeRef you want to find. It's perhaps better to add an Alfresco FormFilter and do it in the repo when the form is submitted...

Comment: Thx for the reply. What I did after all was to use recursive Ajax calls. I don't know if it's the best practice but it works fine.